# Reference error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, cesiumjs

Using hermitespline in cesium project, its returning me an error saying cartesian3 is not defined. Could someone help me what is wrong and how to include this cartesian3 and rectify this error.

documentation on hermitespline:-http://cesium.agi.com/Cesium/Build/Documentation/HermiteSpline.html

documentation on cartesian3:-
http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ljsox/cesium/Cesium-b12/Build/Documentation/Cartesian3.html

it is giving me an error when i try to insert the example code given in hermitespline to the below code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">  <!-- Use Chrome Frame in IE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Use the Cesium Widget to start building new applications or easily embed Cesium into existing applications.">
    <meta name="cesium-sandcastle-labels" content="Beginner">
    <title>Cesium Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Sandcastle-header.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Build/CesiumUnminified/Cesium.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Sandcastle-warn.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="sandcastle-loading" data-sandcastle-bucket="bucket-plain.html" data-sandcastle-title="Cesium (standalone)">
<style>
    @import url(templates/bucket.css);
</style>
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<script id="cesium_sandcastle_script">
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It would be helpful if someone could resolve this issue.

Comment: Do all of the script files load correctly?

Comment: everything is loading correctly, but as i told they say cartesian3 is not defined, could you tell me how to load that to the script to make it working

Comment: Do you have this running somewhere we can look? It would seem that the Cesium.js is not loading.

Comment: codes can be run on there online code editor:-http://cesium.agi.com/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=Custom%20Rendering.html                                                            and the function i need to use is:-                                           http://cesium.agi.com/Cesium/Build/Documentation/HermiteSpline.html

Comment: It would be helpful if someone could figure out what is going wrong because, the lines cannot be plotted with that function

Answer (score 2):

Most of Cesium's documented example code presumes you're using `require` to require in the needed modules like `Cartesian3`.  But for simplicity, the default Sandcastle example uses the combined, minified Cesium.js file, that includes all modules under a single Cesium namespace.

The solution is simple, just replace `Cartesian3` with `Cesium.Cartesian3` for this example.  You will need to do the same for `Cesium.HermiteSpline` itself.

Comment: one more doubt, is there any way i can import a third party function to cesium. Like can I use a function like curve or label from a different project to the cesium project?

Comment: You can certainly import and run code from other JavaScript projects alongside Cesium, but they can't render 3D graphics into Cesium's canvas without some kind of hookup code.  For example you could use jQuery to put DOM labels on top of the Cesium canvas, but you couldn't use ThreeJS out-of-the-box to add labels to Cesium (unless you put a transparent ThreeJS canvas on top of Cesium's canvas, and kept the cameras in sync).